# React return bignumber instead of value

Tags: solidity, react, smart-contract-wallets

I'm trying to ask to a smart contract the balance of it.
The code for obtain the balance in Solidity is this:

```
 function balance() external view returns (uint) {
        uint amount = address(this).balance;
        return amount;
    }
```

Unfortunately when I run the code what I obtain is a block as result:

[image]

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What JavaScript library are you using to query the Ethereum smart contract?

Comment: I'm using React

Comment: contracts return uint in js environments always as big numbers, because js cannot handle and work with those very very big numbers. You need to use libraries to transfer it to a string or a normal number (if  it is safe to do that without overflow or losing data) check this https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/utils/bignumber/

Comment: @Uderr yeah, but React can be used with ethers.js, web3.js, etc. You have to specify what web3 library you're using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using `ethers.js` to interact with your smart contract, it provides a way to interact with Bignumbers and convert them to native JavaScript types. Check this out https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/utils/bignumber/.

Answer (score 0):

Was facing a similar issue you can solve it by,

`return amount.toNumber()`

BigNumber.toNumber( ) ⇒ number
Returns the value of BigNumber as a JavaScript value.

Comment: Just be aware that it might not work well for arbitrarily large numbers. For numbers bigger than Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER it will lose precision.